# Escape $num in Git aliases

Tags: linux, git, git-config, git-alias

I'm trying to alias a simpler stash so I can do `git load <stashname>`, something along this line:

```
load = !git stash list | grep ' $1$' | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed '$ s/:$//'; echo
```

Unfortunately, awk's `$1` is being replaced by the stash name too. How can I escape that $ sign? Tried `\$`, but git says:

```
fatal: bad config file line 33 in /home/alvaro/.gitconfig
```

Comment: No idea about '$' escaping in git config files, but why not simply use an equivalent for that awk line, e.g. `sed 's/ .*//'` (snip everything after the first space).  Or write this as a separate shell script instead of a git alias?

Comment: @AndyRoss if you post that as an answer I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in your oneliner? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Neither occurrence of $1 is being replaced. They are surrounded by single quotes. The `; echo` at the end of the line is just a comment. So it is not really doing anything. If you want that to be part of the alias you need to surround the whole thing with double quotes.

The `<stashname>` is being added to the end of the line (I assume that is what the `echo` is for?) The command you propose seems to want to echo something like `stash@{n}` given the name of the stash. The alias below will do that. (though it is not very useful)

```
[alias]
load = "!git stash list | grep \" $1$\" | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed '$ s/:$//' #"
```

The first occurrence of $1 is replaced by the argument because it is only surrounded by double quotes; which we need to escape. The $1 for awk will not be replaced be `<stashname>`. Besides git already allows you to apply, pop stashed by name.

```
$ git stash list # produces no output
$ echo "something" > else.txt
$ git stash something
Saved working directory and index state On master: something
HEAD is now at 6d3fcf0 merged
$ git load something
stash@{0}
```

perhaps it's easier to see it this way

```
[alias]
test = "! echo $1 '$2' \"$3\" end; # "
```

results in

```
$ git test first second third
first $2 third end
```